# Quitar margenes horizontales en bootstrap con react

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

Quiero dejar en 0 el margen izquierdo y derecho, pero no me deja, he buscado varias formas pero no me permite dejarlo como quiero, [image: lo blanco que se ve arriba es la navegación que ocupa toda la vista del navegador y el formulario no, entonces quiero que el formulario también use todo el espacio del navegador en la horizontal], lo que se ve arriba es la navegación que ocupa todo el espacio horizontal del navegador, mientras que el formulario no, quiero saber como puedo solucionar este problema porque quiero que el formulario también ocupe todo el espacio horizontal del navegador.(si no se entiende quiero quitar todo el espacio blanco que se ve y qué ahí comience el formulario negro.

acá tengo mi código:

```
render(){
return(
    <div>
         <Card body inverse style={{ backgroundColor: '#222', borderColor: '#333' }} className="m1-3">
            <div class="mt-3">
            <CardTitle>Solicite una cotización gratis</CardTitle>
             <CardBody>
                 <Col md={{ size: 6, offset: 3 }}>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="name">Nombre</Label>
                        <Input 
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        placeholder="Nombre"
                        onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="email">Correo</Label>
                        <Input 
                        value={this.state.email}
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Correo" 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="message">Mensaje</Label>

                        <Input type="textarea"
                        name="message"
                        value={this.state.message}  
                        onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Col md={{ size: 6, offset: 4 }}>
                            <Button color="success">
                            Enviar
                            </Button>
                        </Col>

                 </Form>
                 </Col>
            </CardBody>
           </div>
            </Card>
            </div>
)}
```

PD: ocupo react y reacstrap y react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Los márgenes y padding de los objetos los da el contenedor en que despliegas tu elemento, así que debes sobreescribir los valores de padding para el elemento en un css, o directamente en el elemento si no le estás aplicando bootstrap.
en este caso el primer div:

```
return (
  <div style={{padding:0}}> ...
```